# Referring to a column alias in two tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hiveql, wso2-das

I have two hive SQL tables which consist of following columns.

table_1

```
|customer_id | ip_address|
```

region_table

```
|country_name | region_name|
```

**I tried,**

```
SELECT table_1.customer_id, table_1.ip_address, getCountry(ip_address) AS Country, region_table.region_name FROM table_1 JOIN region_table ON region_table.country_name = Country;
```

> getCountry() is UDF which returns the country name when the IP address
>   is passed into it. I want to use that country name to create another
>   column with the corresponding region from the region_table. And i want
>   to get the following table as my output.

```
customer_id | ip_address | Country | region_name
```

Any thoughts on what I'm missing in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      c.customer_id
           ,c.ip_address
           ,getCountry(c.ip_address) as Country
           ,r.region_name 

from                table_1         c

            join    region_table    r

            on      r.country_name = 
                    getCountry(c.ip_address)
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it sorted out this way.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Oracle, you can not refer column alias defined in `SELECT` statement in `WHERE` clause of same query!! Because database engine first evaluates `WHERE` clause and identifies eligible rows and then proceeds to fetch columns as defined in `SELECT` part of query.

In your case, right query should be

```
select 
  table_1.customer_id, 
  table_1.ip_address, 
  getCountry(ip_address) AS Country, 
  region_table.region_name 
FROM table_1 
JOIN region_table ON region_table.country_name = getCountry(table_1 .ip_address);
```

Comment: The explanation is wrong. There is no logical limitation preventing from expressions in the SELECT clause to be recognized in other clauses. This is a matter of parsing and not execution and since the whole statement is known in advance this is no brainer. Teradata for instance does support it and you can use the aliases whenever you like including the WHERE clause and even the SELECT clause itself.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz In case of Oracle, you can refer a column alias from a inner query in outer query (or `WITH` clause), but not as part of `WHERE` clause when same `WHERE` clause is used to derive column alias. example `select full_name , emp_id from (select first_name ||' '||last_name as full_name,emp_id from emp) where full_name='John Smith'` is perfectly OK. In case of Oracle sql, chronologically, WHERE happens before SELECT. I don't know about Teradata, hence I'll restrict my comments to Oracle (updated in my answer as well)

Comment: It is not a matter of any order of any kind. Think of an alias as an macro - a text that can be searched and replaced anywhere in the text of the statement. If I'll give you statement as `select 1 as xxx, xxx+1 as y from t where xxx=1` you'll know exactly what I mean.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, Also, column alias is not just matter of parsing. Since column alias allows any names  parser can not know what should be the correct expression. Consider this example, `select role as "designation", designation as "role" from emp where role='Manager'`. In this case, there will be ambiguity if this column alias referencing is handled at parser level. I believe all ANSI sql compliance RDBMS will prevent referencing column alias in `WHERE` clause when same `WHERE` clause is used for deriving column aliased!

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, doesn't this lead to ambiguity if referencing table `t` has a column with name `xxx`? assume table t is (xxx number, yyy varchar(10)), then how your query `select 1 as xxx, xxx+1 as y from t where xxx=1` will evaluate?  While selecting rows based on `where` condition, will it consider data in table or column alias from `SELECT` part of the query ?

Comment: Yes, this mght lead to ambiguty like a "standard" aliasing might lead to ambiguty. We have to decide (as database providers / iso committy) if to fail the statement or to give presedence to the alias or to the source column

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, Yes, to avoid such ambiguity, most database products do not allow referencing column alias in the places when its decided to arrive at value of referenced column alias (i.e in WHERE clause of same query construct)

Comment: With that logic, CTE/Inline views would not exist